# boost-python Virtual Functions with Default Implementations

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

The recommended way to expose a non-pure virtual function in boost python is to wrap it as shown below.

[boost python doc](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/exposing.html#tutorial.exposing.virtual_functions_with_default_i)

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual int f() { return 0; }
};

struct BaseWrap : Base, wrapper<Base>
{
    int f()
    {
        if (override f = this->get_override("f"))
            return f(); // *note*
        return Base::f();
    }

    int default_f() { return this->Base::f(); }
};
```

Finally exposing:

```
class_<BaseWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Base")
    .def("f", &Base::f, &BaseWrap::default_f)
    ;
```

The document explains

> Take note that we expose both `&Base::f` and `&BaseWrap::default_f`. Boost.Python needs to keep track of 1) the dispatch function f and 2) the forwarding function to its default implementation default_f. There's a special def function for this purpose.

What does this **special def function** actually do, and what is the difference below?

```
.def("f", &Base::f, &BaseWrap::default_f)
.def("f", &BaseWrap::default_f)
```

From the source code in `class.hpp::def_impl`,
I only see **default_f** as a overload function add to namespace too as **&Base::f**.
because of the same signature, **default_f** would replace the **&Base::f**.

Is there any thing I missed? Any suggestions or examples would be a huge help!